# If possible to display a profile page for each subcriber?

Tags: php, wordpress

I Have a page that display all users with their respective information using,

```
<?php $members = get_users(); foreach ($members as $user) {  ?>
   <?php echo get_avatar( $user->ID, 80 );?>  
    <ul>
        <?php 
            $registered = ($user->user_registered . "\n");
            echo '<li>Name ' . $user->display_name .' '. $user->user_lastname . '</li>';
            echo '<li>Joined '. date("M d Y", strtotime($registered));
            echo '</li>';
        ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Now if I enter siteurl/member/username how I can have the information of that user (member)? What im trying to achieve is a a profile page to each user(subscribers)

Comment: Using `<?php $members = get_users(); foreach ($members as $user) { } ?> `will do what I want but because I'm using `foreach ($members as $user) { }` only display the information of the last subscriber. How can I display the information of the current user that isn't the one that is viewing the profile or the last subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

Utilising your existing get_users() function, we can pull out a user by matching attributes.  However you might want to write a more efficient get_user() function.

```
<?php

function get_member_by_user_id($user_id)
{
    $members = get_users();
    foreach($members as $user) {
        if($user->user_id == $user_id) return $user;
    }
}

$username = get_user_id_from_url(); // Some method to get the name from the url
if(! $user = get_member_by_user_id($user_id)) {
    // 404
}
echo $view->render($user); // Or however you do this
```

Comment: Call to undefined function get_username_from_url()  the userid is what im using in the url

Comment: what im trying to achieve is a a profile page to each user(subscribers)

Comment: The get_user_id_from_url() method (that I've renamed), you'll need to write yourself.  That's why it's undefined.